# Bicategories in Haskell

Tags: haskell, typeclass, category-theory

I am trying to define a type class for bicategories and instantiate it with the bicategory of categories, functors and natural transformations.

```
{-# LANGUAGE NoImplicitPrelude, MultiParamTypeClasses, 
    TypeOperators, KindSignatures, Rank2Types, 
    ScopedTypeVariables, FlexibleInstances, InstanceSigs #-}
```

Here is the class for categories:

```
class Category (c :: * -> * -> *) where
  id :: c x x
  (.) ::c y z -> c x y -> c x z
```

Here is the class for functors:

```
class Functor c d f where
  fmap :: c x y -> d (f x) (f y)
```

Here is the composition of functors:

```
newtype Comp g f t = Comp (g (f t))
```

The composition of two functors should be a functor.
However, the following instantiation is not accepted by Haskell because `f` and `g` are not in scope.
How would you define `fmap` here?

```
instance Functor c e (Comp g f) where
  fmap :: c x y -> e (Comp g f x) (Comp g f y) 
  fmap = fmap g . fmap f
```

Here are natural transformations (The parameter c is not used here but is useful for the next instantiation below.):

```
newtype NT f g (c :: * -> * -> *) d =
  NT {unNT :: forall x. d (f x) (g x) }
```

Here is the class for bicategories (The operators `.|` and `.-` are respectively the vertical and horizontal compositions for 2-cells):

```
class Bicategory
  (bicat :: (* -> *) -> (* -> *) -> (* -> * -> *) -> (* -> * -> *) -> *)
  comp where
  id1 :: Category d => bicat f f c d
  (.|) :: Category d => bicat g h c d -> bicat f g c d -> bicat f h c d
  (.-) :: bicat g g' d e -> bicat f f' c d -> bicat (g `comp` f) (g' `comp` f') c e
```

Categories, functors and natural transformations should form a bicategory.
However, the following instantiation is not accepted by Haskell because, in the definition of the horizontal composition `.-` of natural transformations, g in not in scope.
How would you define the horizontal composition `(.-)` here?

```
instance Bicategory NT Comp where
  id1 = NT id
  n .| m = NT (unNT n . unNT m)
  (n :: NT g g' d e) .- m = NT (unNT n . fmap g (unNT m))
```

Comment: `f` and `g` are type-level variables, not value-level variables.

Comment: @DavidYoung: I understand that. But it can be done on paper. So my question is how do you do the same thing in Haskell?

Comment: You didn't specify a `Category` instance for `c` and `e` (and you also didn't give them a `Category` constraint), so it's impossible. As it is written, `fmap` must work for all possible choices of `c` and `e`. There is an implicit `forall`. For example, what would it do if `c` is `Const` and `e` is `Tagged`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's make it a little easier to compose functors by defining a record getter for `Compose` (no need to abbreviate, we're among friends):

```
newtype Compose g f t = Compose { unCompose :: g (f t) }
-- Compose    :: g (f t) -> Compose g f t
-- unCompose  :: Compose g f t -> g (f t)
```

In order to make `Compose g f` a `Functor c d`, we need a way to lift functions into the category `d`, so let's define one:

```
class Category c => Arr c where
  arr :: (x -> y) -> c x y -- stolen from Control.Arrow.Arrow
```

Now we've got everything we need:

```
instance (Functor c d f, Functor d e g, Arr e) => Functor c e (Compose g f) where
  -- c                      :: c x y
  -- fmap_cdf c             :: d (f x) (f y)
  -- fmap_deg (fmap_cdf c)  :: e (g (f x)) (g (f y))
  -- arr Compose            :: e (g (f y)) (Compose g f y)
  -- arr unCompose          :: e (Compose g f x) (g (f x))
  -- arr Compose . fmap_deg (fmap_cdf c) . arr unCompose 
  --                        :: e (Compose g f x) (Compose g f y)
  fmap c = arr Compose . fmap_deg (fmap_cdf c) . arr unCompose
    where fmap_cdf :: forall x y. c x y -> d (f x) (f y)
          fmap_cdf = fmap
          fmap_deg :: forall x y. d x y -> e (g x) (g y)
          fmap_deg = fmap
```

Here we have to use `AllowAmbiguousTypes` (in GHC 7.8), as the category `d` disappears completely, so it's ambiguous.

Now for `Bicategory`.

Let's simplify `NT` - we don't need that phantom parameter.

```
newtype NT c f g = NT { unNT :: forall x. c (f x) (g x) }
```

Now we can make a simpler `Bicategory` definition:

```
class Bicategory (bicat :: (* -> * -> *) -> (* -> *) -> (* -> *) -> *) comp where
  id1   :: Category c => bicat c f f
  (.|)  :: Category c => bicat c g h -> bicat c f g -> bicat c f h
  (.-)  :: (Functor c d g, Arr d) => bicat d g g' -> bicat c f f' -> bicat d (comp g f) (comp g' f')
```

Which we can implement:

```
instance Bicategory NT Compose where
  id1 = NT id
  NT n .| NT m = NT (n . m)
  -- m              :: c (f x) (f' x)
  -- fmap m         :: d (g (f x)) (g (f' x))
  -- n              :: d (g (f' x)) (g' (f' x))
  -- n . fmap m     :: d (g (f x)) (g' (f' x))
  -- arr Compose    :: d (g' (f' x)) (Compose g' f' x)
  -- arr unCompose  :: d (Compose g f x) (g (f x))
  -- arr Compose . n . fmap m . arr unCompose
  --                :: d (Compose g f x) (Compose g' f' x)
  NT n .- NT m = NT $ arr Compose . n . fmap m . arr unCompose
```

[Here's a gist of the complete code](https://gist.github.com/rampion/aa9e8a7a61853c3042e7). Compiles fine with GHC-7.8.2.

Comment: Thank you @rampion. I still need to work out your answer but this seems to answer the first part of my question. Is the answer to the second part (i.e., the last setence of my post) similar?

Comment: You are almost there. But I am afraid I cannot accept this answer as it is because it is restricted to endofunctors.

Comment: The extension `AllowAmbiguousTypes` is not supported by GHC 7.6.3 but your code is accepted after removing this extension. I am however confused by the class `Arr` you use. It appears to allow the lifting of any Haskell function of type `x -> y` into a morphism of type `c x y` of a category `c`. But a category does not necessarily contains all Haskell functions as morphisms.

Comment: Bob: True, but you need some way to lift `Compose`/`unCompose` from functions to morphism.  You could alternately require that the the categories you want to create `Functor` and `Bicategory` instances for all support `class Composable c where compose :: c (g (f x)) (Compose g f x) ; uncompose :: c (Compose g f x) (g (f x))`.

Comment: Bob: alternately, you could define `arr` as a simple function, rather than a member of a type lass, with `arr :: (Category c, Functor (->) (->) (c x)) => (x -> y) -> c x y; arr f = fmap f id`. But again, that would limit which categories you could talk about.

Comment: Bob: any more questions?

Comment: No more question. That's it. Thank you.